# Is it possible to prevent a page break within a block of TeX in plain tex?

Tags: tex-core, plain-tex

This is equivalent to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2210638/391161), but I am working in Plain Tex and not LaTeX. As an example, I'd like to allow page breaks only before the `\exper{}` line in the following block, assuming I have multiple such blocks.

```
\exper{Stanford Computer Science, Operating Systems}{January 2016 -- March 2016}
\jtitle{Course Assistant}
\sub{
Held office hours to answer student questions
}
\sub{
Graded assignments for coding style and correctness.
}
```

All of the commands above are simple formatting commands I have defined for a resume.

Comment: can you not make all the block a third argument to `\exper` (and put it in a vbox to stop breaks) ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, Is `vbox` is the proper technique in plain `TeX` to prevent page breaks? If so, I'll accept that as an answer.

Comment: it'll work the other way (arranging there are penalties of 10000 harder to set up with no knowledge of the macros being used and what other penalties may be around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you change the syntax to

```
\exper{Stanford Computer Science, Operating Systems}{January 2016 -- March 2016}{%
\jtitle{Course Assistant}
\sub{
Held office hours to answer student questions
}
\sub{
Graded assignments for coding style and correctness.
}
}
```

Then you can arrange that `#4` of `\exper` is placed in a `\vbox{...#4...}` and it will not break.

Comment: Would it work to place the whole block in a `vbox` to make the whole block atomic with respect to page breaks?

Comment: @merlin2011 yes that's probably what I meant, although of course since you provided no example code I am answering in the dark, mostly.